# Wildcard Use in Fortran Where Query

Tags: fortran, where-clause, wildcard

I have a question concerning the use of the Fortran Wildcard. I want to use it in a Where/Elsewhere-Query to extract values according to years. To describe the data: I have hourly values for specific variables, and I want to extract the data according to a specific year (later I want to replace the hard coded year to a variable to loop over all years). But for the moment I am interested in applying the wildcard correctly so that my mask with which I multiply my data variables subsequently will be extracted.

The time array looks like:

```
    2021121404.00000     
    2021121405.00000     
    2021121406.00000     
    2021121407.00000     
    2021121408.00000
```

I want to select and create and apply the mask as follows:

```
  Where (time == '1990'%)
       mask = 1
  Elsewhere
       mask = 0
  End Where

  TEMPobs = TEMPobs*mask
  PRECobs = PRECobs*mask
```

I just do not know how to state the WHERE clause with the WILDCARD correctly.

Can anybody help me with that simple question?
I would be very grateful.

Comment: What type is the time array? Can it always be converted into a floating point number? I'm also totally unsure what you think the % does, or even what makes you think that Fortran provides "wildcards", but this might not be an issue.

Comment: This is how time is defined:   REAL(KIND=dp),ALLOCATABLE,SAVE :: xobs(:,:),time(:),TEMPobs(:),PRECobs(:)

Comment: So, something like `where (int(time/10**6)==2021)` ?  Also, you can make the assignments to `TEMPobs` and `PRECobs` inside the `where` construct, you don't need to create the `mask` array explicitly.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did work with your proposed line. Nonetheless, can you also explain to me how it works? How exactly do I have to understand `(time/10**6)`?

Comment: `time` is a real number, dividing it by `10**6` moves the digital point 6 places to the left, then `int` truncates what's left.  If you still don't understand work through a few examples with pencil and paper.